# ember.js bindings and scope inside of blocks

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The problem is, inside of the App.ListViewItem the listController is undefined, it's like inside the #each block you lose the things defined in the containing scope.  Any one know if this is expected behavior, or if there is a way to do it that I'm missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv9qM/8/)

Feel free to tell me whatever else I'm doing that is complete crap.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle? [You can use this](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/8Z2Fc/) as a starting point.

Comment: edited, code has been fiddled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is use `parentView.listController`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebryn/kv9qM/9/